# Arduino IDE detecting wrong port

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm very new to Arduino and I am using an Arduino Uno. I connected my Arduino to my computer and selected the correct board in the Board menu in the IDE, but I see `COM3 (Arduino Mega 0r Mega 2560)` in the port menu instead of COM3 Arduino Uno. I even opened the Device Manager and under the COM & LPT ports saw the same, `Arduino Mega 2560 (COM3)`.

What can be the possible solution? Please help.

Comment: First, are you sure that it is Arduino Uno? Then if yes, from Tools->Board->Arduino AVR Boards->Arduino Uno. Also if you are a beginner, you might wanna try [Arduino web editor](https://create.arduino.cc/editor/) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But I double-checked, Yes my Arduino is and Uno, I tried using the web editor, I also tried to upload the code on my Arduino by selecting the Mega 2560 in the boards . . . none seemed to work for me  :/

Comment: In the web editor, it should automatically detect, what does it say?

Comment: It detected Mega 2560

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-mega-is-recognized-as-arduino-uno/632129/5

Comment: Could you please add a link to a picture from your board? Are you using a clone board? This is certainly strange. You could burn the Uno's bootloader to your board in case something was incorrectly programmed by whomever sold you your Arduino

Answer (score -2):

Select arduino uno if you are using arduino uno.

Select arduino 2560 if you are using 2560.